# Gremlin SimplePath query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

Below is the graph that I have

```
graph.addV("ORG").property(T.id, "ORG1").property("orgId", "ef5c").iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP1").property("compId", "2112896").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge1").from(__.V("ORG1")).to(__.V("COMP1")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP2").property("compId", "2100198").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge2").from(__.V("COMP1")).to(__.V("COMP2")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP3").property("compId", "4007384").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge3").from(__.V("COMP2")).to(__.V("COMP3")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP4").property("compId", "4031986").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge4").from(__.V("COMP3")).to(__.V("COMP4")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP5").property("compId", "2116697").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge5").from(__.V("COMP4")).to(__.V("COMP5")).iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge9").from(__.V("COMP4")).to(__.V("COMP5")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP6").property("compId", "2116698").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge6").from(__.V("COMP5")).to(__.V("COMP6")).iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge10").from(__.V("COMP5")).to(__.V("COMP6")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP7").property("compId", "6040").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge7").from(__.V("COMP6")).to(__.V("COMP7")).iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge11").from(__.V("COMP6")).to(__.V("COMP7")).iterate();
graph.addV("ORG").property(T.id, "ORG2").property("orgId", "3ef3").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "5779").property(T.id, "edge8").from(__.V("COMP7")).to(__.V("ORG2")).iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge12").from(__.V("COMP7")).to(__.V("ORG2")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP8").property("compId", "2106827").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge13").from(__.V("ORG1")).to(__.V("COMP8")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP9").property("compId", "2106829").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge14").from(__.V("COMP8")).to(__.V("COMP9")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP10").property("compId", "2104080").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge15").from(__.V("COMP9")).to(__.V("COMP10")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP11").property("compId", "2110851").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge16").from(__.V("COMP10")).to(__.V("COMP11")).iterate();
graph.addV("COMP").property(T.id, "COMP12").property("compId", "4020209").iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge17").from(__.V("COMP11")).to(__.V("COMP12")).iterate();
graph.addE("edge").property("sub", "951a").property(T.id, "edge18").from(__.V("COMP12")).to(__.V("COMP4")).iterate();
```

I have also created the graphical representation where we can execute the queries as well, on this link https://gremlify.com/3eswz64l2nk/3

I have tried the below query

```
List<Path> routes = graph.V().has("orgId", "ef5c").repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).until(__.hasLabel("ORG")).dedup().path().toList();
```

This gives me a single path

```
Route : path[v[ORG1], e[edge1][ORG1-edge->COMP1], v[COMP1], e[edge2][COMP1-edge->COMP2], v[COMP2], e[edge3][COMP2-edge->COMP3], 
v[COMP3], e[edge4][COMP3-edge->COMP4], v[COMP4], e[edge5][COMP4-edge->COMP5], v[COMP5], e[edge10][COMP5-edge->COMP6], 
v[COMP6], e[edge7][COMP6-edge->COMP7], v[COMP7], e[edge12][COMP7-edge->ORG2], v[ORG2]]
```

Also tried below solution
`g.V().has("orgId", "f5c") .repeat(bothE().dedup().by("sub").otherV().simplePath()) .until(hasLabel("ORG")).emit().path()`

This gives me the 2 paths, which I am expecting, but it is not going to until condition that means giving path only till next vertex, Any idea, if we can take this upto vertex with label ORG

Expectations:
I am expecting 2 different routes from ORG1 to ORG2.

I have few restrictions

1. I need to use bothE() on each vertex so that I can identify the routes irrespective of edge direction, which really don't matter in my use case. It also helps me to identify all incoming and outgoing paths from a vertex.

Comment: If you expect alternative paths using either of the double edges between vertices, you can try the configuration withBulk(false). I expect more than two paths, though!

Comment: The `dedup` will remove all other routes to the same target.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence yes, but without dedup it gave way more then actual complete path, as in my case path should start from ORG and end at an ORG.

Comment: @HadoopMarc will check that and let you know

Comment: open for suggestions

Comment: I’m mostly AFK this week @ParveshKumar - if no one has responded before I can submit an answer next week

Comment: Rather than checking for an "ORG" label, you could just check for the "ORG2" ID. That will ensure the paths only include those that reach ORG2